# can I override next session binding <prefix>-) in tmux?

Tags: tmux

I want to bind this to something more convenient, like `M-]` without the prefix:

```
bind -n M-] send-prefix \; send-keys )
```

in my tmux.conf doesn't work.

What's my mistake?... I also tried `C-]` and some others. When I'm at a prompt, it just writes the `)` character, so the prefix isn't being captured by tmux.

There doesn't seem to be a command for "next session", just the predefined binding.

Comment: Isn't there a `next` command?

Comment: @melpomene `next` is short for `next-window`, I want next session

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put these lines in my `.tmux.conf`:

```
bind j switch-client -n
bind k switch-client -p
```

As you can see the -n and -p arguments are next and previous. Enjoy!

Comment: This works! I don't know how I missed this when reading through `man tmux`.

Comment: Believe me, you are not the only person. That manpage is huge!